# Not being able to inherit the logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have a class called logger and some other classes that are inheriting the attributes of the logger class.

```
class logger:
    def __init__(self, corr, log_set) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        if (self.logger.hasHandlers()):
            self.logger.handlers.clear()
        file_handler=logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent, 'python_' +  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + '.log'))
        stream_handler=logging.StreamHandler()
        log_set['corr'] = corr
        format_str = {"timestamp":"%(asctime)s", "loglevel": "%(levelname)s", "process": "myProcess", \
        "source": "Me", "name": "Mike", \
        "logger": "%(funcName)s", "message": "%(message)s"}
        format_str.update(log_set)
        format_str = json.dumps(format_str)
        stream_formatter=logging.Formatter(format_str)
        file_formatter=logging.Formatter(format_str)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(stream_formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler) 
                       
    

    def shutdown_logger(self, logger):
        logger.handlers.clear()
        logger.shutdown()


class auth:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def validate_settings():
        pass



class au(auth, logger):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    #headers to be sent to the API authentication call. 
    def set_headers(self, headers):
        self.logger.info("starting something")
        
        if headers == 'default':
            header = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        else:
            #possibly add validation for structure of headers.
            header = headers
        
        return header


a = au()

print(a.set_headers("default"))
```

This errors out by giving the error `AttributeError: 'au' object has no attribute 'logger'`

I am fairly new to this but I thought since I defined the logger in the `__init__` method of the base class, the derived class should be able to find the logger.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The fact that you didn't get a runtime error should have been a clue.  Your `logger.__init__` requires two positional parameters, and you haven't passed those anywhere.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah I was hoping I would be getting that error, the fact that I wasn't was what I wasn't understanding. Thanks!